# Is React-bootstrap compatible with React 18?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I would like to migrate my application to React 18 but after doing so, I got errors like this

```
This JSX tag's  children  prop expects a single child of type  ReactNode , but multiple children were provided.
```

or

```
Type  () => Element  is not assignable to type  () => ReactNode 
Type  Element  is not assignable to type  ReactNode 
Property  children  is missing in type  Element  but required in type  ReactPortal
```

I looked at React-bootstrap code on github (version 2.9.0 at time of writing) and it still uses React 16.

Should it work?

I made sure that the same version of `react` and `@types/react` is used by all dependencies, using `npm ls xxx`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I looked at React-bootstrap code on github (version 2.9.0 at time of writing) and it still uses React 16.
>
> Should it work?

Yes, it should.

The [npm page of the project](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-bootstrap?activeTab=dependencies) doesn't even state `react` as a direct dependency, and if you look at the `peerDependencies` section of the [`package.json` file](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/master/package.json):

```json
"peerDependencies": {
  "@types/react": ">=16.14.8",
  "react": ">=16.14.0",
  "react-dom": ">=16.14.0"
},
```

it states that it requires React 16 *or higher* as a [peer dependency](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/peer-dependencies).